# Issue while running Monthly Cron Expression with Airflow

Tags: cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler

i need some help understanding the behaviour with monthly Cron expression `[43 10 3,8,12 */3 *]`  with `start_date` as `datetime(year=2019, month=11, day=18, hour=1, minute=30, second=0 , tzinfo=pendulum.timezone("UTC"))`  and `end_date` as `None` . This has backfill set as true .

Current Date is: **2020-10-19**

As per my understanding it should not have triggered last two runs `10-03` and `10-08` . Can someone please help me understand this behavior? Also if it is triggering run for `execution_date` of `10-03` and `10-08` then why not for `10-12`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you elaborate on "it should not have trifggered the last two runs"?

The cron expression `43 10 3,8,12 */3 *` matches:

> “At 10:43 on day-of-month 3, 8, and 12 in every 3rd month.”

A good tool to validate cron expression is [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#43_10_3,8,12_*/3_*).

The execution date 10-12 hasn't triggered yet, because of how Airflow handles `execution_date` - see [airflow scheduler](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html):

> The scheduler won’t trigger your tasks until the period it covers has ended e.g., A job with schedule_interval set as @daily runs after the day has ended. This technique makes sure that whatever data is required for that period is fully available before the dag is executed. In the UI, it appears as if Airflow is running your tasks a day late

> Let’s Repeat That, the scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

This means the run with execution date 2020-10-12 10:43:00 will be triggered just shortly before 2021-01-03 10:43:00.

Comment: Is it the case that it applies to immediate run. For e.g as you mentioned  "This means the run with execution date 2020-10-12 10:43:00 will be triggered just shortly before 2021-01-03 10:43:00"  . Wouldn't it be the case that  2020-10-12 10:43:00 will execute just before 2021-01-12 10:43:00  and not 2021-01-03 10:43:00 as interval is of 3 months?  Does it apply that interval on month basis only or specific to day within a month like 2020-10-03 to 2021-01-03, 2020-10-08 to 2021-01-08

Comment: The interval is not 3 months - it's quite irregular based on your cron expression. Airflow will always calculate the next execution_date, you didn't specify 3 schedules but one.

Comment: Ahh, i got it. */3 in cron expression for month column just signifies running every 3 months but interval between each run is not precisely 3 months as there are runs with few days of gap (within same month) so in a way it is irregular interval. did i understand right?

Comment: Correct - cron expression always just define one interval and it can be quite irregular.